# Coldfusion Retrieving stored keys in a hashtable as an array

Tags: coldfusion, hashtable

I am writing a Coldfusion component that is supposed to work as a wrapper for Java's hashtable and some of its methods. I am using Coldfusion 8.

Now to my specific problem:
I have instaniated a Java hashtable object and I am writing a function that is supposed to get all the stored keys of that hashtable and store them in an array, so I can then loop through that array in a Coldfusion application.

Here is what I got so far for that function:

```
<cffunction
    name="getKeys"
    access="public"
    returntype="array"
    output="false"
    hint="Returns all existing keys in an array">

    <cfscript>
        var keyArray = arrayNew(1);
        var e = myHashtable.keys();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
            arrayAppend(keyArray, e.nextElement());
        }

        return keyArray;
    </cfscript>         
</cffunction>
```

I am fairly new to Coldfusion and I am just wondering if I am following the right approach or doing it totally wrong. Every help or tip is very much appreciated.

Comment: You might be better asking this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From where does the object, "myHashtable" come?

Comment: Is there a reason you need a Hashtable specifically? Normally, you would use a CF structure (which is a `java.util.Map` object). Then to obtain an array of keys, use [StructKeyArray()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f00.html).  The link is for CF9, but that function should exist in CF8 as well.

Comment: And if it doesn't, `ListToArray(StructKeyList(Struct))`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this on ColdFusion 8, but you should be able to get an array of key names from a `java.util.Hastable` by using the `java.util.Collections` `list` method. For example:

```
<cfscript>
hashtable = createObject("java","java.util.Hashtable");
hashtable.put("a", "ant");
hashtable.put("b", "bear");
hashtable.put("c", "cat");

arrayList = createObject("java", "java.util.Collections").list(hashtable.keys());
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#arrayList#">
```

If you wanted to get an array of the values you could do this:

```
hashtable.values().toArray();
```

That might work better for you than looping and appending to the ColdFusion array.